# Wordpress Visual Editor broken, it disappeared

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

I don't know how the visual editor broke, it has just disappeared.

1. users >> Profile >> Visual Editor check box - it's ok
2. I don't have permissions for editing wp-config.php, for add code `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );`
3. I removed all plugins

I have permission for editing files into /themes and admin panel. 
Can you help me to fix this problem?

Inspect element shows:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'example.com/blog/wp-admin/post-new.php'; was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,800,500,300,400‌​';. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

Comment: do inspect element, console and check errors

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/post-new.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,800,500,300,400'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.<br> Problems at http,I think the problem is not this

Comment: Your error there you gave is because SSL and regular isn't fixed. It has nothing to do with your Visual Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using wordpress with incorrect SSL configuration

Possible solutions are:

1. Make sure that the settings > site url & blog url both have SSL version
2. Install `SSL Insecure content` WordPress plugin and configure it properly
3. Install `cloudflare` WordPress plugin and configure it too if you're using cloudflare
4. Hire a professional (I can fix this too for your site if you're interested)